# Multiple backgrounds with the same image

Tags: css, background-image

If the same picture is used twice as a background for the same element like this:

```
    url(http://i.imgur.com/On0lt.png) -162px -551px no-repeat,
    url(http://i.imgur.com/On0lt.png) -200px -530px no-repeat,
```

will it be loaded twice?

Comment: Why should the whole line be disregarded? I use it this way and it works pretty well. Or do you mean just the url part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it'll only get requested once.

You can verifiy that from the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools. It'll just show one request.

Answer (score 0):

No it should only be loaded once so you'll be fine time wise :)